# Antialias on clipPath on layout

Tags: java, android

I have a layout, which has several views inside of it - toolbar, recyclerview and few separators (which are simple views with height of 2dp and match_parent width). I wanted to put a mask on a layout - most important part of it are the round corners for whole layout (and not the views itself). I decided to create my own LinearLayout class with overloaded dispatchDraw function and I managed to get nice result... except for one thing - those corners are not antialiased.

tl;dr is there ANY way to put antialias to clipPath function? I know can turn it on in Paint and then use xfermodes to mask the layout, however I have no clue how to draw mask and then draw everything else (without knowing what's exactly inside).

Here is my layout code (except for classname, simple constructors and Path field):

```
@Override protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (path == null) {
        path = new Path();
        float margin = MyApplication.getInstance().getMetrics().density * 5;
        path.addRoundRect(new RectF(margin,margin,getWidth()-margin, getHeight()-margin),
                margin*2, margin*2, Path.Direction.CW);
    }
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}

@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37626545/2252830), of course instead of `mMask.draw(canvas)` you would need to call `canvas.drawPath()` with a `Paint` set with `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN` mode

Comment: Post this as a reply so I can set it as a solution, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37626545/2252830), of course instead of `mMask.draw(canvas)` which is a "mask" made by a `NinePatchDrawable` you would need to call `canvas.drawPath()` with a `Paint` set with `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN` xfer mode